# Space Curve: Equation of normal plane at point...

Tags: differential-geometry

If I have the space curve $r(t) = \langle t, t^2, t^3 \rangle$, how would I find an equation of the normal plane to $r(t)$ at the point $P(2,4,8)$?

Comment: Think how to find normal vector of this plane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A plane containing the origin with normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ is given by $\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{x}=0$ (this is simply a state-ment of orthogonality). As corollary, a plane containing the point $\mathbf{p}$ is given by $\mathbf{n}\cdot(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p})=0$.
2. A plane normal to a curve $\gamma$ at a point $\mathbf{r}(t)=\mathbf{p}$ is exactly the plane containing the point $\mathbf{p}$ with normal vector given by the curve's tangent vector at this very point, $\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{T}(t)=\mathbf{r}\,'(t)$.
3. For what $t$ is $\mathbf{r}(t)=(2,4,8)$? What is the derivative $\mathbf{r}\,'(t)$ evaluated at this particular time $t$?

Comment: N.B. $\mathbf{n}\cdot(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p})=0$ is what is termed as the Hessian normal form of a plane.

Comment: I got x+8y+48z=162 Is this correct?

Comment: @user1008134: No. What's $\mathbf{n}$ and what's $\mathbf{p}$ for the plane here?

Answer (score 1):

The normal vector at the point P is (1,4,12) and the normal plane is given by $x+4y+12z=114$ using Hessian normal form of a plane.